# jQuery losing .on() event when attaching DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Sorry for the code dump below, but it is all the relevant code for the issue and I stripped out anything superfluous or sensitive.  I am creating a series of buttons using .on('click', function() {}) event listeners and they seem to be lost at some point between when the event listener is being created and the button being added into the table.  I had an issue with this sort of thing before, but it was with DOM objects being detached and reinserted into a document, which I have tried the fix for that, but it isn't working.  Here the entire table is emptied and rebuilt when it updates from the server, so the event listeners should be getting created anew each time.  I am at a loss for where they are getting lost.

```
function submitCommand(command, jobID) {
    //Open API connection and submit
    var url = "http://IPADDRESS:8082/api/jobs"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST", url, true)
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var jobs = xhr.responseText
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
            console.table(jobs)
        } else {
            console.error(jobs)
        }
    }
    test = JSON.stringify({"Command":command, "JobID":jobID})
    xhr.send(test)
    console.log(command+" "+jobID)
}
function buildControls(jobID) {
    var div     = document.createElement("div")
    var cont    = $(div).clone(true)
    var restart = $(div).clone(true).css({"display": "inline-block", "width": 20, "height": 20, "background-image": "url(img/refresh.png)", "background-size":"contain"})
    restart.attr("id", "restartButton"+jobID)

    $("#restartButton"+jobID).on('click', function() {
        submitCommand("requeue", jobID)
    })
    $(cont).append(restart)
    return cont
}
function jobRow(jobObject) {
    //create and format table elements
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    var cel = document.createElement("td")

    //Create cells for data
    var controls = $(cel).clone(true).attr("id", "controls"+jobObject._id).append(buildControls(jobObject._id))

    //Insert cells into row, then return row
    var jobRow   = $(row).clone(true).append(controls)
    return jobRow
}
async function buildJobsView() { 
    //create pane elements
    var tbl = document.createElement("table")
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    var tth = document.createElement("th")

    //build base table
    var headings = ["Job Controls"]
    var header = $(row).clone(true)
    for(h in headings){
        temp = $(tth).clone(true).append(headings[h])
        header.append(temp)
    }
    baseTable = $(tbl).clone(true).append(header)
    $("#jobsTable").append(baseTable)

    //populate jobs
    let jobList = JSON.parse(await getJobs())
    for(job in jobList) {
        $("#jobsPane table").append(jobRow(jobList[job]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the event handler like this:

```
$("#restartButton"+jobID).on('click', function() {
    submitCommand("requeue", jobID)
})
```

...which means "search the document for this ID and attach the click handler." The problem is that the element isn't attached to the document yet, so it's not finding the element. Therefore no handler can be assigned.

Since you're building the element in that function, you already have a reference to it. Attach the handler to that element reference directly instead of trying to select what you already have.

```
var restart = $(div)
  .clone(true)
  .css({
    display: "inline-block", 
    width: 20, 
    height: 20, 
    "background-image": "url(img/refresh.png)", 
    "background-size":"contain"
  })
  .attr("id", "restartButton"+jobID)
  .on('click', function() {
    submitCommand("requeue", jobID)
  });
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense... let me try that.
edit: Ok, that worked for that problem, but now the server isn't executing the commands, but that's likely just a problem with the JSON object I'm sending's structure.  I should be able to debug that on my own, thank you SO much.  I needed to finish the PoC before tomorrow morning, and this has me down to this one last problem to debug.  Thank you THANK YOU!!!